# How to make permanent changes to sshd_config file?

Tags: hadoop, ssh, localhost, sshd

I am trying to configure a Hadoop MapReduce environment on my Ubuntu system. I created a new user called `hduser` and put it under a new group `hadoop`. I created a ssh certificate and added it to the authorized keys. But whenever I tried to connect to the localhost, I ran into trouble since it kept on asking for password rather than using the key authentication.

I got over this by adding the user `hduser` to the `AllowUsers` list in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. I was able to connect to the localhost and get the HDFS system running.

Now the problem is that the entry I made for `hduser` in the `sshd_config` file is getting removed  everytime I shutdown the Hadoop servers. So, each time, before starting Hadoop processes, I have to make the entry again in `sshd_config` file and `reload ssh`. Is there any way to make the changes permanent so that I don't have to do this every time?

I also tried commenting out the `AllowUsers` field, but it gets automatically uncommented each time.

Thanks,
TM

`Edit:` I talked to the system admins and it seem that the system wide configuration management application is updating the config files every now and then. Got my Hadoop users added to their list and now things work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Did you perform these steps:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ''

...

Your identification has been saved in /home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa.

Your public key has been saved in /home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.

...

    $ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

    $ ssh localhost
```

These lines are from this [tutorial](http://codesfusion.blogspot.com/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 0):

how to create shh-keygen and how to copy the ssh-copy in the localhost.
Cloud you do bellow commands and try the hadoop it will run.

ssh-keygen -t rsa

ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $USER@hostname

exmp(hostname= your hostname like localhost). Then it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment...but it doesn't make any difference...the entries for AllowUsers in the sshd_config files are getting removed still...